# MapBox.js Place Names Zoom Level

Tags: mapbox

I am creating an application using MapBox.js, I would like to display all place names at Zoom Level 13 in MapBox Streets but some place names only will display at Level 14. Does anyone know if it is possible to change this preset on MB Streets without having access to their Style Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time as this is pretty much burned into the streets layer (streets, streetnames, and place names). If you want further customization, I would suggest looking into TileMill and using something like the [OSM Bright Quickstart](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/) to make custom basemaps.